# MeteorJS: how to change localhost to custom domain?

Tags: javascript, configuration, dns, meteor, meteorite

I am trying to deploy my test meteor js application to own virtual server and stuck.

Some installed modules, for example `accounts-github` for OAuth, use `Meteor.absoluteUrl` method which doesn't recognize current domain and returns results like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/github?close
```

How to teach meteor to setup `custom.domain` instead of `localhost`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to do that (for now) is to [modify your environment variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_absoluteurl) `ROOT_URL`, for example before meteor run:

```bsh
ROOT_URL=http://my.domain:3000/ meteor --port 3000
```